# Unable to update Chrome extension: Invalid version number in manifest: 0.1

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-web-store

I'm trying to update my Chrome Extension but when I upload the new one at the Chrome Web Store I get this error.

I tried version: 1.0, 0.1.1, 0.1.2.3 etc..

> An error occurred: Failed to process your item.
>
> Invalid version number in manifest: 0.1. Please make sure the newly
>   uploaded package has a larger version in file manifest.json than the
>   published package: 2.0.

```js
{
    "name": "Stylish Eve",
    "description": "Fashion, Hairstyles, Outfits, Home Design and Architecture Blog Magazine", 
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "icon-16.png",
            "38": "icon-38.png",
            "128": "icon-128.png"
            }, 
        "default_title": "Stylish Eve", 
        "default_popup": "labnol.html"
    }, 
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",
    "version": "0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the version number to something larger than 2.0 (as it says in the error). 2.0 was probably the last version that you published and the next one has to be bigger.